# Rendering the default image when the user removes the current image

Tags: ruby, image, rubygems, carrierwave

I'm trying to render the default image when the user removes the current image. I used the carrier wave gem for uploading the image. This is my application.helper.rb code. Application.helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def avatar(image)
    return '100_2.jpg' unless image

    image

  end
```

I put this code for rendering the default image, but it does not work. How can I change the code to render the default image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the result of this method intends to be. Is it a link? If so, then [image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path) method might help to construct such a link:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar(image)
    image || image_path('100_2.jpg')
  end
end
```

Or you might want to [provide a default url](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url) to your uploader:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("100_2.jpg")
  end
end
```